# Definition of joint eigenvalue of $n$ matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ be matrices of size $m \times m$. What is the definition of joint eigenvalue of $A_1, \ldots, A_n$? Joint eigenvalues are different from common eigenvalues? I tried to find the definition on google but didn't find it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've never heard the term "joint eigenvalue", but I suspect it means the same as "common eigenvalue". It might help if you add to the question where it is that you encountered the term.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I found this term in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05724.pdf). Page 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joint eigenvalues of an $n$-tuple $(A_1,\dots,A_n)$ of $m\times m$ matrices is the subset of $\mathbb C^n$ consisting of those $n$-tuples $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ of complex numbers such that there exists a non-zero vector $v$ in $\mathbb C^m$ such that
$$
A_jv=\lambda_j v, \text{ for all }j=1,\dots,n.
$$
Note that the same vector $v$ is an eigenvector for each $A_j$, thus the word 'joint'. The vector $v$ is called the joint eigenvector. It is known that if the matrices $A_j,\; j=1,\dots,n$ commute with each other, then the set of joint eigenvalues is non-empty.

Hope this helps.
Cheers!