# Relationship between joint eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ and eigenvalues of $A^{-1} B$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, symmetric-matrices

An early-ish paper$^1$ on the Riemannian structure of the manifold $\mathcal{P}(n)$ of symmetric, positive-definite matrices gives the following formula for the geodesic distance between two such matrices:

$$
\begin{align*}
d^2_{\mathcal{P}(n)}(P_1,P_2) = \Vert \log(P_1^{-1}P_2) \rVert^2_F = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln^2(\lambda_i), &&&&&&(2.9)
\end{align*}
$$

where "$\log$" is here understood as the matrix logarithm and $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $P^{-1}P_2$. However, the [pyRiemann implementation of this distance](https://github.com/pyRiemann/pyRiemann/blob/master/pyriemann/utils/distance.py#L289) (which cites this paper) documents the computation of this distance as

$$
d^2_{\mathcal{P}(n)}(P_1,P_2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln^2(\lambda_i),
$$

where $\lambda_i$ are the ***joint eigenvalues*** of $P_1$ and $P_2$. With a cursory search, I did not find a result showing that the joint eigenvalues of two matrices $A$ and $B$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $A^{-1} B$, and it is not immediately obvious to me if that's true or why it would be. Are these two spectra actually the same (or is there some straightforward relationship between them?), or is there an inaccuracy in the implementation? Thanks!

1. *Moakher, Maher*, [**A differential geometric approach to the geometric mean of symmetric positive-definite matrices**](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0895479803436937), SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl. 26, No. 3, 735-747 (2005). [ZBL1079.47021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1079.47021).

Comment: Looking at the source, it seems to be computing `eigvalsh(A, B)`. From [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigvalsh.html), it seems that that computes the eigenvalues of $B^{-1} A$, with some normalisation conditions on the eigenvectors. So I think that's probably just what they mean by "joint eigenvalues", which does indeed agree with the result from your paper (since you're squaring the logarithm). The terminology "joint" for that is a bit nonstandard as far as I know - it conflicts with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2881728/473276) for example.

Comment: Ah, yes, ok! That was the source of my confusion. But you're right, the scipy documentation does confirm we're computing eigenvalues of $B^{-1}A$ -- I wonder if the pyRiemann documentor misread "eigvalsh" as "eigenvalues-shared" instead of "eigvalues-symmetric/Hermitian" and took "shared" as a synonym for joint or something. Thank you!